# JVM - Print Stack trace without explicit call

Tags: java, jvm, stack-trace, jvm-arguments

Is there a way in java to print a stack trace of any exception in a catch block without making code modifications. I was told that there was a JVM arg you could use to produce stack traces of all exceptions for debugging, although I can't find any documentation on this. The only solution I can think of for this is to use aspectj and create an aspect on any exception that is created and print the stack trace. I was hoping there was a better solution than aspects.

Thanks,
Steve.

--Edit--
So what I want to find out is lets say I have this code:
    try {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    //Ignore exceptions
    }

I would like to see the e.printStackTrace() even though no call is made to it. This can help with debugging a jvm crash I am seeing, and there is a lot of error hiding going on.

Comment: Not able to understand the question

Answer (score 2):

As Marko Topolnik said, logging *any* exception may take a bit of work, but you can also implement a custom uncaught exception handler to do whatever you please with uncaught exceptions.

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("EXCEPTION");

    public void uncaughtException(final Thread t, final Throwable e) {
        log.logp(Level.SEVERE, "EXCEPTION", "", "Unhandled exception in thread " + t.getName() + ": ", e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Better solutions would only exist for *unhandled* exceptions. There is no first-class support to log  *any exception, anywhere* that happens inside normally functioning code. I would recommend you try with aspects and intercept the `Throwable` constructor calls, if that's at all possible. If possible, you may still get false positives because instantiating exception does not entail throwing it.